# MS Access DLookup Multiple lookup Runtime error 13 type mismatch

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have what I think is a simple problem, but I must be missing something.

This line of VBA works:

```
If Me.To = 340 And DLookup("[LocID]", "[qryMyLocation]") = "C25" Then
```

However, I need to test against 2 LocID's and this doesn't work:

```
If Me.To = 340 And DLookup("[LocID]", "[qryMyLocation]") = "C25" Or "C20" Then
```

What am I missing - is the above possible?

I receive the error when trying the 2nd line of code: Runtime error 13 type mismatch

Comment: "C20" is not a boolean expression.  `DLookup("[LocID]", "[qryMyLocation]") = "C20"` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Try this:

```
If Me.To = 340 And (DLookup("[LocID]", "[qryMyLocation]") = "C25" Or DLookup("[LocID]", "[qryMyLocation]") = "C20") Then
```

Note that I added some parenthesis, too.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you need to write the comparaison again, VBA doesn't understand "C20" as a valid boolean expression.

```
If Me.To = 340 And ((DLookup("[LocID]", "[qryMyLocation]") = "C25" Or DLookup("[LocID]", "[qryMyLocation]") = "C20")) Then
```

To get faster results, you can store the DLookup into a variable.

```
Dim LocID as Variant 'Put the right type here, I think it should be String
LocID = DLookup("[LocID]", "[qryMyLocation]")
If Me.To = 340 And (LocID = "C25" Or LocID = "C20") Then
```

Edit : I added the parenthesis the same as the accepted answer because of operator precedence. Leaving the parenthesis out would result in

```
If (Me.To = 340 And LocID = "C25") Or LocID = "C20" Then
```

Comment: If I use the variable solution I receive run time error 91 - Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Use `Dim Val As Variant`.

Comment: Edited to fix the type, I always mix them up

Comment: just so you know, val is also a function name that evaluates a string to see if it a number

Answer (score 1):

A lookup only returns one result, but you can add your desired results in the criteria and count the returned results.

```vb
If Me.To = 340 And DCount("[LocID]", "[qryMyLocation]", "[LocID] = 'C25' Or [LocID] = 'C20'") > 0 Then
```